# Compare string to array

Tags: c#, json

I want to compare a string (postcode, e.g:"50000") to array of string elements and if the array contain the postcode stated, it need to select the "PSHid" of the array. I managed to deserialized the Json file but not I'm stuck how to compare my postcodes. Here is my code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    public class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kayh1105/msiaPostcodes/main/ShortList_MsiaCitiesPostcodes";
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            string jsonResponse = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse);
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MsiaPostcode>(jsonResponse);            
        }
    }
}

public class MsiaPostcode
{
    public _State[] state { get; set; }
}

public class _State
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public _City[] city { get; set; }
}

public class _City
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int PSHid { get; set; }
    public string[] postcode { get; set; }
}
```

and below is my Json sample:

```
{
  "state": [
    {
      "name": "Wp Kuala Lumpur",
      "city": [
        {
          "name": "Kuala Lumpur",
          "PSHid": 1,
          "postcode": [
            "50000",
            "50050"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Setapak",
          "PSHid": 2,
          "postcode": [
            "53300"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Johor",
      "city": [
        {
          "name": "Ayer Baloi",
          "PSHid": 3,
          "postcode": [
            "82100"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Ayer Hitam",
          "PSHid": 4,
          "postcode": [
            "86100"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Yong Peng",
          "PSHid": 5,
          "postcode": [
            "83700",
            "83710"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First flatten the list of states (*many to many relationship* : Many states, each state can have multiple cities) into list of cities.

After getting list of cities filter by Postcode,

To Flatten the list of list into one sequential list

> [SelectMany():](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-7.0) Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

```
var PSHids = data.state
    .SelectMany(x => x.city) //Convert list of states into list of cities
    .Where(x => x.postcode.Contains("50000")))  //Filter by postcode
    .Select(x => x.PSHid) //Select PSHid property only
    .ToList();   //Convert IEnumerable<int> to List<int>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple LINQ query like so, it'll select the cities first, then query them to get only the set where a postcode matches your input, "50000" in this case, then select the `PSHid`, and then finally return it as a list.

```
data.state
    .SelectMany(x => x.city)
    .Where(x => x.postcode.Any(y => y == "50000")))
    .Select(x => x.PSHid)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: yeah my bad, missread the json, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

to find PSHid you don't need any custom classes at all, parse the json and use Linq

```
   string postCode = "50000";

    int PSHid = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse)["state"]
        .SelectMany(x => x["city"])
        .Where(x => ((JArray)x["postcode"]).ToArray().Contains(postCode))
        .Select(x => (int)x["PSHid"])
        .FirstOrDefault(); //  1
```